# Swift - For loop returning nil array

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to create a for-loop that will append data to an array after each iteration. I am getting "[]" (nil) as a response when I try to print the array. Here is my code:

```
    class func fetchChartPoints(days: Int, base: String, target: String, completion:@escaping (_ chartPoints: [Double]) -> ()) {

    let datesArray = formatDate(days: days)
    var array = [Double]()

    for date in datesArray {
        Alamofire.request("http://api.fixer.io/\(date)?base=\(base)").responseJSON { response in

            //print(response)

            if let resultJSON = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject]  {
                let rates = resultJSON["rates"] as? [String: Double]

                array.append((rates?[target])!)
            }
        }
    }
    completion(array)
    print(array)

}
```

Comment: You already have a completion function (good!) – but you are calling it at the wrong place (bad!). Are you aware that Alamofire requests are handled *asynchronously*?

Comment: To add to this comment, even if you move your print into the completion handler of your request, the results will be nondeterministic, it is a race condition. There is no guarantee of the order of the responses for each request and your completion will get called for every response in whatever order they come in.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I am new to Alamofire so I did not know that they were handled asynchronously. Is there any other solution I could use?